# SceneNode transform and Eye and Center position

Tags: camera, scene, scene-graph

I am learning some inner workings of game engine development and have come across this confusion. To explain what I am trying to do, I want to start with an example:

Let's say that I have an object (e.g a cube) that moves forward. I want to add a camera that follows the object (e.g 3rd person camera). For this, my SceneGraph looks like this (XML type markup to show hierarchy):

```
<GameObjectNode mesh="cube.mesh" position="(0.0, 0.0, z)">
    <CameraNode position="(0.0, 10.0, 15.0)" />
</GameObjectNode>
```

This allows my camera to "follow" the cube because the camera's world transformation is:

```
camera.worldTransform = parent->worldTransform * camera.transform;
```

This all makes sense in terms of transformations in the world. However, when it comes to view transforms, this is where I am confused about. All the hardware APIs use have something like `setViewTransform(float *matView, float *matProjection)` and the view matrix is typically calculated using something like `lookAt(vec3 eye, vec3 center, vec3 up)`.

My camera transform is calculated using the formula above. However, the lookAt matrix function requires position as vector (eye). Is there a way to create lookAt matrix function that does not use vectors to get position? Or is there a way to extract position from transform matrix?

EDIT: I was able to use the worldTransform matrix last "vector" to get the position vector as that's where the translation parameters were. However, I still have a problem with center one because the the center vector must also be calculated using matrix transform. How can I get the coordinates of center in relationship to Eye.